# Mediaelement.js IE8 Flash Video Not Working

Tags: javascript, flash, iis, internet-explorer-8, mediaelement.js

I'm trying not to duplicate problems, but this is something that I've been been battling for a while and none of the solutions I've come upon here helped my situation.  I am in the process of moving my site over to an SSL certificate-enabled IIS 7 server from another IIS 7 server.  I copied all files over, fixed the urls, made sure the proper MIME types were accepted (including .swf files).

Now, within IE8 (because it uses Flash, I assume), my videos are displaying a blank screen.  All other HTML5 browsers, it works just fine.  Is there some other reason on the server side that this issue is occuring?

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904736/flash-fallback-video-black-screen-no-video-only-audio-media-element Changing .me-plugin position to static fixed it for me.