# flash fallback video black screen - no video, only audio media element

Tags: flash, mediaelement.js, fallback

I just downloaded mediaelement.js from http://mediaelementjs.com.
Looks really good.

Though in the demo files, the videos won't play in IE 8.
The player is showing a black screen, but I can hear the audio.

I have also tried installing on a server only to get the same problem.
Can anyone enlighten me, any help would be much appreciated.

10 mins later...
Cured, fixed, all good. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13983402/1565597) below.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same exact problem. I wonder if the postion: absolute; only triggers the bug in certain conditions? Since the current mediaelement.js also includes this bug, so apparently nobody cares enough to fix it.

Comment: What a great find. I've wasted a lot of time trying to isolate this problem. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Chemi, would you mind posting youf finding as answer (on your own question). Thus, it might get upvoted.

Comment: I needed to make both .me-plugin and .mejs-mediaelement have static positioning to work in IE8:  .me-plugin, .mejs-mediaelement { position: static !important; }

Answer (score 6):

> The problem was position:absolute on the css .me-plugin amazing
>
> I really hope this helps others. It was a total fluke that I tried it.

Comment: Yes, amazing !! The problem is definitely that css position attribute for the class ".me-plugin" in mediaelementplayer.css. The fix is to simply comment out "position: absolute" or change it to "position: relative", whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone has troubles with flash fallback in ie8, for me that code helps:

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player', {
    /* ... place your options here ... */
    enableAutosize: true,
    success: function(player, node) {
        player.setVideoSize(480,325);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Mediaelement.js` works in IE8 if you set the `position: static;` and not `absolute` as it currently is, to the div with the class `.me-plugin`.
It will still show a black video if you test with IE9 Browser Mode IE8. Just check with IeTester or on a pc with XP.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Even after changing ``position:static;`` it doesn't seem to work for me if it's in a jQuery UI Dialog box. Is that because the dialog itself is ``position:absolute;``? Any way around this?